# How to change reference dll by Pre-Build command line in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

We have a console application which is connecting with Oracle database. For some legacy reasons, the Oracle client in my local computer and windows server are in different versions.

While I am debugging in my local computer, I use `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` of version A. Before pushing exe to windows server, I will switch the project to Release mode, and change the referred `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` into version B, which is from another folder, and build out the exe, then push it to server.

Now I want to make these steps automatic. While building in Release mode, I want to let Viusal Studio Pre-Build command to change the referred Oracle.DataAccess.dll for me. Is there any command I can use? Or, Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [a NuGet package for `OracleClient`](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Oracle) instead?

Comment: It is a very legacy project and our team is not using Nuget. By the way, if I use Nuget, can  
 I change the referred dll version using command before building?

Comment: I think a better idea would be to drag the project, kicking-and-screaming, into using NuGet instead of trying to force ugly hacks like that into working. You can always _incrementally_ transition to using NuGet packages too. The longer your team procrastinates on this the harder (and more expensive) it will be in future... (if there are breaking API changes in newer OracleClient versions then surely there's an older version available as a NuGet package that you can use that won't require code-changes?)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the DLL is a managed one, yes?

I had to do this for a project in which I needed two different versions of a DLL, one for Debug, one for Release.  I should say that I did manage to get my build procedure to copy the proper version of that DLL to my output directory before my build.  In fact, that is the location where my entire project referred to it.  So all I needed to do was have the reference in the .CSPROJ file refer to my build output directory with the proper macro.  I did it like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="GS.Sdk_v142">
      <HintPath>$(OutDir)\GS.Sdk_v142.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi @Joe. It sounds like a good idea. But this will modify .csproj file, and our project is managed by Git, including this file. I don't want my change to affect other developers. I am still thinking if I can reach it by some command.